# 'Post Your Question' button disabled after adding too many tags and unable to enable it again

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, asking-questions

I just tried to ask a question on SO and when I pressed the 'Post Your Question' button I got the error that I can't use more that 5 tags and the button got disabled. After removing a tag so the total of tags got to 5 the button was still disabled. I've tried removing and adding all the tags again but I can't seem to enable the 'Post Your Question' button again. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Browser:
Google Chrome version 35.0.1916.114 m

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this and couldn't.  I added 6 tags, received the error message, but the button was not disabled.  Is there a specific set of steps you did that ended up getting the button disabled in the first place?

Comment: @psubsee2003 are you using chrome? I just reproduced it again 2 times.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Did you try on SO? I was able to reproduce there with Firefox, but not on MSO.

Comment: Yeah I'd only tried on MSO. On SO I can repro in Safari

Comment: @Daanvn I just tried it with Chrome, on both MSO and SO, entered 6 tags, got the error message, but the button is still active.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Strange, I know it doesn't work on MSO but on SO you should get the same result.

Comment: @psubsee2003, did you hit submit? I can also reproduce in chrome 35 (mac os x)

Comment: @OGHaza no, I didn't try to submit the question first, from the way the question was worded, I expected the button to be disabled without any other action.  That is probably the difference

Comment: Repro on Mac, Safari 7.

Comment: Tried an reproduced here too (Chrome on Windows). One error in my console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict) https://stackoverflow.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask`

Comment: Repro in Firefox 29.0.1 on windows 7, nothing in the console though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [new validation step that was recently added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/warning-or-confirmation-on-new-tag-creation/233897#233897) uncovered an old bug here that was previously rare enough to go by unnoticed. I'm deploying the fix as we speak, so this should be back to working correctly in a few minutes. It's a JavaScript fix, so to be precise, it'll work correctly if the page was *opened* after the fix was deployed.